# Appcelerator/ Titanium Alloy - No Andriod SDKs were found under the specified SDK Location

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-mobile

I am running Appcelerator on OSX.
When I try to set up an emulator on the Appcelerator IDE, by clicking:

- "Run Configurations..." >
- "Appcekerator Android Emulator - appname" >
- "Emulator"

On the bottom of the screen it shows up with an error message saying:

> Problems detected with the SDK settings. Click here for details

Upon clicking for more details, it shows the error message:

> An error was detected with the SDKs configuration
>
> Reason:
>   [Android SDK Home] No Android SDKs were found under the specified SDK location

The value i have put for Android SDK home was:

```
/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: What's the location of your android-sdk root folder? It should be this path and it should not be inside Library folder, but rather in some other public folder.

Comment: Well I'm not sure then. I thought that was the root folder

Comment: I keep my android-sdk main folder in **/Users/prashant/android-sdk** location

Comment: @PrashantSaini I have no such folder like that

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the **Emulator** which are slow and heavy in terms of Memory Usage, I would suggest you to use the **GenyMotion** for Android which is quite fast and easy to use and has close features to a physical device.

But First this First, setup the Android SDK for Appcelerator through **Preference** > **Platform** > **Android** and browse the Android SDK folder and Android NDK.

Note : This can be anywhere in the system folder.

[image: Have a look at this image]

You can download the **GenyMotion** Tool from the below link : https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/

Setting up the tool is quite simple and is given in the image itself.

**Good Luck, Cheers**

Comment: My SDK is in `/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk` and I don't even have a '/Volumes/data/' directory. The error message still appears!

Comment: @YahyaUddin : Just try pasting your path and just append **boot** in the beginning. Hope this will solve the issue.

Comment: I tried both `boot/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk` and `/boot/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk` but it predictably said the directory does not exist

Comment: @YahyaUddin : Just copy the SDK in your Data folder or any other public folder and the give its path. It should work, as it has nothing that can be done on our side other than giving the correct path. Where the IDE can find the Android SDK.

Comment: @YahyaUddin : You can download the **android-sdk** from this link as well : https://android-sdk.en.softonic.com/mac

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as above. I did move my Android SDK home out of '~/Library/' folder.

Previously it was:
'~/Library/android-sdk-macosx'

Then i moved it like:
'~/android-sdk-macosx/'

Most probably, the Library folder not visible to AppceleratorStudio. My guess.

Thanks a lot, guys.